# Can I execute only certain Tasks from a Package in a deployed SQL catalog?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2017

In a deployed SSIS project, is a Package the smallest executable unit?
Is there any straight way to execute only certain tasks within a Package - like in Design Mode?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use parameters to switch on and off sections of a package for different runs but that would need to be factored in while building it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought at the beginning: to build some control flow tasks, etc.. But I was wondering if there was a way to do it without them,cleaner/simpler way, etc. Thanks a lot for your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this functionality is not available yet but parameters allow to run certain task as per the run requirement.

You may also try using environment to setup your run if that is more consistent.